# Regular expression to show that all strings contain each symbol atleast once

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

I'm studying for my exam and I came across the following exam question from last year, the only way I know how to solve this is build a regex that accounts for all six different series of letters so for example to recognize a string that has the letters a,b and c occur in that order:

$(a+b+c)^*a(a+b+c)^*b(a+b+c)^*c$

The question:
Give a regular expression r over the alphabet A = {a, b, c} such that the
language determined by r consists of all strings that contain at least one occurrence of each symbol in A. Brieﬂy explain your answer.

Comment: I think an alternation of six terms of the form $a(a)*b(a+b)*c(a+b+c)*$ is easier to explain. BTW: What has been *your* question?

Comment: @greybeard: yeah, i belatedly got that. I deleted my comment while thinking about how to prove that formulation in a way that justifies "easier to explain" since it seems to me that OP's formulation requires very little explanation at all.

Comment: @greybeard: The big advantage of yours, it seems to me, is not ease of explanation but rather the fact that it leads to a deterministic grammar. OP's expression is a classic example of exponential state blowup of the standard regex->NFA->DFA algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution looks good to me, and it is probably what they expect of you.

It is interesting to consider the more general question: how large does a regular expression for this language be, as a function of the size of the alphabet? Denoting the size of the alphabet by $n$, [Theorem 9 here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~yuvalf/CFG-LB.pdf) shows a lower bound of $\Omega(c^n)$ for some (explicit) $c > 1$. (The theorem is for context-free grammars, but a regular expression can be translated to a context-free grammar.) Your construction is $O(n\cdot n!) = 2^{O(n\log n)}$, so there is a some gap here.

Comment: But cba is not in the OP’s language?!

Comment: The regular expression in the post is only one among six different summands. Please read the post carefully.

Comment: indeed, I suspected that to be the case, but the language was unclear enough to leave me wondering. Oh well. Were I a grader, I would have expected something more definite

Answer (score 0):

Spelling out the six alternatives in their most symmetrical form:
(a+b+c)* a (a+b+c)* b (a+b+c)* c (a+b+c)*  +
(a+b+c)* a (a+b+c)* c (a+b+c)* b (a+b+c)*  +
(a+b+c)* b (a+b+c)* a (a+b+c)* c (a+b+c)*  +
(a+b+c)* b (a+b+c)* c (a+b+c)* a (a+b+c)*  +
(a+b+c)* c (a+b+c)* a (a+b+c)* b (a+b+c)*  +
(a+b+c)* c (a+b+c)* b (a+b+c)* a (a+b+c)*

Comment: Thanks for answering.  However, we're not looking for answers that consist solely of an equation or regular expression; we'd like you to support your answer with explanation of how you got it or rationale or justification that it is correct.  Can you [edit] your answer accordingly?  Thank you!